# How do you expose class in a module to the global namespace in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

### The Problem

Given

- I have an existing application containing both modules and global scripts (regular non-module scripts).

  - modules

    - App.ts
  - global scripts

    - **alpha.ts** contains a class named alpha
    - **beta.ts** contains a class named beta
    - **gamma.ts** contains a class named gamma
- I want to convert one class in a global script (**gamma.ts**) into a module

  - via adding `export default` before  `class gamma {}` in **gamma.ts**
- I want to import class `gamma` into the global namespace (i.e the window object) so it can be accessed by the existing global and module scripts.

## What I have tried

I have tried a bunch of things around **global.d.ts**

e.g.

```
import gammaAlias from "../scripts/gamma";
export as namespace NS_Global;

declare global {
    var qqq: {n:string};
    namespace ZZZ {
       export var gamma: gammaAlias;
    }
    var gamma: gammaAlias;
}
```

But none has worked

i.e. TypeScript tells me one of the following

- gamma does not exist
- `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`

### github

> I have a github repo set up to investigate these questions.
>   https://github.com/penguin020/expose-typescript-modules-globally
>
> ConvertToModulesPOC_original is the working "before" case.
>
> ConvertToModulesPOC is a broken attempt to convert gamma .ts to a
>   module and expose it globally.

### PS

The question remains, how do you expose a module to the global namespace?

Any answers using the examples in the github would be particularly appreciated!

Comment: I think `declare global` is only a type declaration, it doesn't actually do anything. You'd need to actually assign `window.gamma = gammaAlias` to *create* the global variable.

Comment: Setting the [`module` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to None or System should work. Although it doesn't seem to be documented well, so maybe you'll fare better by emitting ES6 modules and then properly bundling them with rollup or webpack, which both have options to expose various exports as global variables.

Comment: Fixed the alpha problem

Comment: @Bergi -  I am constrained to use the angular cli for production, and plain system.js for development.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot even use a [tsconfig file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)? It might help if you could share more of your configuration, e.g. how you call angular cli and how you use system.js.

Comment: The target system uses CLI.  This question should just assume I am using no build system beyond tsc, as is specified in the github.  You can see how I use system.js there (I load a single entry point from the index.html file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an answer here in "[TypeScript: exposing module types in the global context and why to avoid it](https://web.archive.org/web/20210515083432/https://designprincipia.com/typescript-exposing-module-types-in-the-global-context-and-why-to-avoid-it/)";

I have updated the github repo.

The most salient changes I found were:

---

*in **tsconfig**:*

```
"module": "system",
```

---

in **yMod.ts**

```
import gammaAlias from "../scripts/gamma.js";

declare global {
    export type gamma = gammaAlias;
    export const gamma: typeof gammaAlias;
}

(window as any).gamma = gammaAlias;
```

note: You *could* have the global ambient declaration in another file, even a *.d.ts file.

---

The [link above](https://web.archive.org/web/20210515083432/https://designprincipia.com/typescript-exposing-module-types-in-the-global-context-and-why-to-avoid-it/) breaks down the reasons for having **three references for each symbol to be exposed** globally.  It is pretty well explained on that page, so I will only summarize here:

1. Expose the class **type** to the TypeScript compiler (no code generated)
2. Expose the class **object** to the TypeScript compiler (so there is an object to call **new** on; no code generated)
3. Extend the window object to expose the class in the global namespace (generates code).

Comment: If anyone can find a better way to do this, I will happily award the bounty.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you think is lacking/bad about your solution? From what I can tell, that approach is the idiomatic way of doing it. Disclaimer: I've only read the code, not tried compiling or running it

Comment: Maybe something similar to "export as namespace" that does not generate an unnecessary namespace.  I am having to reference each module I want to expose globally 3 times, which seems ... profligate.

Comment: Out of those 3 operations, two is on the type level (`export type` and `export const`), referring to two different things in TypeScript (types and values, respectively). The last operation is the actual code operation that needs to performed for the type level operations to work. So seeing as you're doing three things with three operations I don't think it's going to get much better.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You want to expose '*gamma*' to the global namespace so that you can call '*gamma.log()*' straight from '*window*' or from the console?

Add the following 2 lines into gamma.ts at the bottom of the class.

```
let g = new gamma();
(window as any).gamma = g
```

1) The first line initializes a new *Gamma* class into variable **g**.

2) The second line exports **g** into the global namespace so that it can be called from '*window.g*' or simply just '*g*'.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR4zk.png)

Pull request #1: https://github.com/penguin020/expose-typescript-modules-globally/pull/1/files

---

I also suggest moving these two lines of code into your main initialization file '*app.js*'.

gamma.ts

```
export default class gamma {
```

app.ts

```
import gamma from "./gamma";
let g = new gamma();
(window as any).gamma = g
```

Pull request #2: https://github.com/penguin020/expose-typescript-modules-globally/pull/2

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, as I wanted the class gamma, not an object instance of the class to be exposed globally. +1 for the try though.

Comment: That's even easier then as it's already exposed to the global namespace.

Just shift gamma.js to be the first script imported. Then call "(new gamma()).log()" in alpha or beta or in your console.

https://github.com/penguin020/expose-typescript-modules-globally/pull/1/commits/4e37ab897a79cb076cc473a97371a8a23df56b95

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  I only wish I didn't have to rename the interface.

```
declare global {
  interface IMyClass extends MyClass { }
}

class MyClass {

}
```

or

```
declare global {
  type IMyClass = MyClass;
}

class MyClass {

}
```

Comment: Problem is that only the type is exported to global namespace but not the implementation. Thus, you cannot do `new IMyClass()`.

Comment: For exporting under the same name, I found that TypeScript accepts `declare global { type MyClass = typeof MyClass; }`. Sadly, it seems that it does not find all symbols of the original class in the newly declared global-namespace-class. Don't know why